# Unable to handle event in background push notification

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I am using cordova plugin add phonegap-plugin-push plugin for push notification
In forground notification works fine.and i can handle event also.
When my app is in background then i got notification as well but on click of push notification my event is not fire.
I am using below code

```
$cordovaPushV5.initialize(options).then(function() {
                // start listening for new notifications
                $cordovaPushV5.onNotification();
                // start listening for errors
                $cordovaPushV5.onError();

                // register to get registrationId
                if (PNdeviceToken == null) //becuase registration will be done only the very first 
                {
                    $cordovaPushV5.register().then(function(registrationId) {
                        // save `registrationId` somewhere;
                        window.localStorage.setItem('PNdeviceToken', registrationId);
                        $rootScope.fcmToken = registrationId;
                        console.log(registrationId)
                        alert("first time registered id -- " + registrationId)
                    })

                } else {
                    $rootScope.fcmToken = PNdeviceToken;
                    alert("already saved registered id -- " + $rootScope.fcmToken)
                }

            });


$rootScope.$on('$cordovaPushV5:notificationReceived', function(event, data) {
                console.log(event)
                console.log(data)
                })
```

When i tap on background push notiction then $cordovaPushV5:notificationReceived event not fire, How can I solve this problem?

How can i handle background push notification event?

Answer (score 0):

I had the Same issue and got it resolved it after 2 days of research.

Handling the notification events is **same** whether the app is in foreground or background.

We have to set **"*content-available*" : "1"** in the data field ***while pushing notifications***. Else it wont call `notificationReceived` event if app is in background.

Also note this is not possible as of now through [Google Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/).

We have to send our [custom payload messages](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/admin/send-messages) (data or notification or both) seperately using any one of the [firebase servers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/server.html#choose).

Detailed info can be found on the plugin's [GitHub Docs Page on background notifications](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/blob/master/docs/PAYLOAD.md#background-notifications).
Quoting from there -

> On Android if you want your **on('notification') event handler*** to be called when your app is in the background it is relatively simple.
>
> First the JSON you send from GCM will need to include "content-available": "1". This will tell the push plugin to call your on('notification') event handler* no matter what other data is in the push notification.

*`on('notification')` event handler = `$cordovaPushV5:notificationReceived` event in your case.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44453799/5213405) for sending custom payload messages using **PHP** and **NodeJS**