# How to app run forever

Tags: cordova, ionic2, ionic3

how to run app forever in background like whatsapp ?

I need when app is killed receive notifications.

I tried many way to this.But still not wrk.

I have no idea.

Kindly advice me,

Thanks

Comment: I had a similar issue when working with Vivo Mobiles, later found out that there was a setting to allow apps to monitor notifications. So i believe it should be a setting with OS somewhere to allow your app receive notification even after killing it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.Can u pls help me.How i fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

> how to run app forever in background like whatsapp?

App will be running forever in backgroung unless it is killed explicitly.

Even for Whatsapp if you kill it by pressing **Force Stop** button in `Settings->Apps->Whatsapp`, It can't receive any notifications unless you start it manually by opening the app. Also if the app is configured to **Block** all the notifications (in `Settings->Apps->YourAPP->Notifications->Block all`) then it won't receive any notifications.

> I need when app is killed receive notifications.

Yes. The app can recieve notifications when it is in background(not forcefully stopped). In cordova I assume you are using [phonegap-plugin-push](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push) for receiving notifications. The `on.notification()` event handler function will be called when notification is recieved.

Two cases when the app is running -

1. **Foreground** - When app is in foreground, the notification is recieved and `on.notification()` event handler function will be called by default.
2. **Background** - When the app is in background, Only notification is recieved. `on.notification()` event handler function will **not** be called by default. You need to set `"content-available" : "1"` in the data field while pushing notifications. And you cannot do this using Firebase Console. You need to have [custom payload servers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/server.html#choose) for pushing notifications.

Refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44453799/5213405) for sending custom payload messages using PHP and NodeJS.

Comment: Thanks for ur reply.I still dont understand.Can u pls explain.How to write background service for app in keep running forever

Comment: you don't need to write a service for that. It will be by default running forever in background. For example check in `Settings->Apps`. So why do you want a service for that?

Comment: Ya.I used phonegap - push plugin.I click hardware(end all) button.my app is closed.but the same time whatsup is not closed.how?

Comment: what is hardware(end all) button? can you elaborate? Also please provide code samples in the question. It will be helpful to get better insight.

Comment: i mean closed all app.i closed my app.i go to settings->App.My app is not running.at the same time closed my whatsup.and check settings->App.whatsup is running.also i restart my phone whatsup is run.

Comment: Thanks for ur patient.I refer this link https://devdactic.com/ionic-2-push-notifications/ . Kindly pls advice me